# Ubuntu 16.04 : configure a group to change date via GUI without admin privileges

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, sudo, sudoers

On Ubuntu 16.04, I would like to create a group of users, named "group_1", without admin privileges who would be able to change the date.

To do so, I use the command **visudo** and add the line :

```
group_1 ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/date
```

Each user of "group_1" is now able to change the date using the CLI:

`date -s "Aug 01 01"`

But I would like to know if there is a way to configure the OS to let the group of users change the date using the Gnome interface (GUI) ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: the command to launch the datetime settings GUI with unity is:

```
unity-control-center datetime
```

Do not allow this command in the /etc/sudoers file because it can be used to create an admin user